# Augmented Reality: Just marker recognition

Tags: java, image-processing, augmented-reality, markers

Think about the usual augmented reality implementations: there's one or more marker, the software recognize the markers and usually shows something on top of them.

I'm interested just in the first part. I need an algorithm, component, framework or class to determine if a given marker is present or not in a photo.

Where can I start from? I prefer a component for Java or C++, but I'm not limited by these languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should see opencv' detectors: [Feature Detection](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/feature_detection.html) (there is example, **find_obj.cpp** sample shipped with opencv package). The most popular algorithm is described and implemented in ARToolKit (just google it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this if this is helpful or not, but for Java, you might look at [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing). It is a barcode reader library, but the task of reading QR codes amounts to recognizing 3-4 markers in the barcode. You might find its approach reusable.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) for C++ (also has Python bindings) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need to track an object through a video. There are several ways to do that with [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) which are explained in their page on [Motion Analysis and Object Tracking](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=tracker).